# file refusing to traverse... keep outputing the same variable content and over again

Tags: c++, file, traversal, stdvector

I kind of have of an issue with the file pointer. For some reason I can't find of way to make it traverse and output every word in document.txt. All it does is to output the same variable content aka the same word even skipping the very first one.(thus it would output the second word over and over again and would stop after the traversal)

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()       

{        
    vector<string>  myVector;
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    ifstream docFile("document.txt");

    string inputline;

    getline( docFile, inputline);

    string word;


    while(!docFile.eof())
    { 
            int i = 1;
            docFile >> word;
            myVector.push_back(word);
             cout<<myVector[i]<<endl;
            //  char c = getc(docFile);
            //  if(c == '\n')
            //  ++linecount;
            //  cout<<linecount<<endl;

            ++i;
    }
}
```

the commented code is just me trying to increment the number of line each time it traverses each line.

Comment: Change `I++` to lowercase, because `I++` and `i++` are not the same. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: The first word is lost because of the `getline` call which consumes it.

Comment: Please post real, actual code, instead of fantasy code, with random parts removed. Note, that this does not mean that you should post massive amounts of completely unrelated code. Edit your question, and replace the totally made-up code here with a [mcve].

Comment: dasblinkenlight, thanks for your feedback it was actually a typo I will correct it right away.        and @Sam Varshavchik? I have just edited my fantasy code to an "real, actual code" like you wanted. Previously I have shorten it just to fact that it would prevent other people to help me out... my actual project is actually bigger than this... all I wanted to know was why the file won't traverse like I wanted to. And also I have been struggling on how to count the line in a file for days. I just wish there were somebody out there to help me.. I mean... my project is due in 2 days.

Comment: No, it's painfully obvious that this is still fantasy code, and it is not "real, actual code". Real, actual code compiles. Yours doesn't (since the variable `i`, that's being incremented, is still not declared anywhere), and since the question is supposedly about code that compiles, but doesn't produce the right result, what's shown here must still be fantasy code. If you want "to know was why the file won't traverse like I wanted to", a [mcve] is required, and not code that still doesn't compile. You can't expect help for code that you still have not shown. Fail.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik,  The number of line start at 1, so I have added int i = 1 for clarification.. is it still good enough? I have read "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" and tried to organize it to the best of my ability. I really don't expect you to write the code for me, I just want a brief explanation on what I am asking.

Comment: Yes, and this was precisely your bug. This was the key, missing information. This is a textbook example of why a [mcve] is mandatory. No exceptions. There is no substitute for a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 1;
docFile >> word;
myVector.push_back(word);
```

Initially, `myVector` is empty, and `push_back()` adds the first word to the vector. As you know, array indexes start with 0, so the first word will go into `myVector[0]`.

```
cout<<myVector[i]<<endl;
```

Since `i` is one, this will attempt to print `myVector[1]` instead of `myVector[0]`. In fact, since `myVector[1]` does not exist, this is now undefined behavior, and a likely crash. You claim that there is no crash and execution continues; which is still within the scope of "undefined behavior", so let's continue.

On the next iteration of the loop, the same four lines of code will execute. The second word now gets `push_back()`ed into `myVector[1]`. `i` gets initialized to 1, again, and `myVector[1]` gets printed.

On the next iteration of the loop, the same four lines of code will execute. The third word now gets `push_back()`ed into `myVector[2]`. `i` gets initialized to 1, again, and `myVector[1]` gets printed instead of `myVector[2]`.

On the next iteration of the loop, the same four lines of code will execute. The fourth word now gets `push_back()`ed into `myVector[3]`. `i` gets initialized to 1, again, and `myVector[1]` gets printed instead of `myVector[3]`.

And so on, and so forth. On each iteration of the loop, the next word gets added to the vector, but because `i` gets initialized to 1 every time, and `myVector[1]` gets shown.

`i++` at the end of the loop does absolutely nothing. Because `i` gets declared inside the loop, when the loop runs to the end `i` gets destroyed, and on the next iteration of the loop, `i` gets initialized to 1, again.

To fix the bug, `i` needs to be declared outside of the loop, and initialized to 0, and not 1.

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik  thanks for your explanation. It was extremely helpful. Bless you man!  I am still kind of new to this site but I promise I will make better post next time. haha.  I guess I won't forget about  -Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example- anytime soon.